# Is there a way to make an exception inside of an expect?

Tags: python

```
    a = int(input("Put in the lower number: "))
    b = int(input("Put in the higher number: "))
    number = random.randint(a, b) 
    guessCache = -1
    finished = input("Whenever you feel done type 'done'")
    running = True
    while running:
        try:
            guess = int(input('Guess: '))
            if finished == "done":
                break
            elif guess == guessCache and guessCache != -1:
                print("Same")
            elif guess > number:
                print("Smaller")
            elif guess < number:
                print("Larger")
            elif guess == number:
                print("Congratulations! You found my number.")
                running = False
            guessCache = guess
        except:
            print("Not a number!")
```

This is the code, and my question is how i should put that "done" should be also an expection and when the user types in "done" the code should break the infinite loop.

Comment: you should not have a bare except. I'd put an `except ValueError` just after the `guess = int(input(...))` to capture that specific exception when converting the input to an int.  If afterwards you have code that might throw another exception, put that code inside a different try / except clause

Comment: I'd capture the input, check if it is done first, and then if not try to convert it to an integer.

Comment: related editor war: using exceptions for managing control flow - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Answer (score 0):

It is often a bad habit to catch all exceptions as you do here:

If you instead choose the type of exception(s) you want to catch then all other exceptions will be thrown further upwards.

In your case trying to use `int()` on something that is not a number will throw `ValueError` exception.

```
try:
    #Some code that throws an exception
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number")
except OtherException:
    #Handle the other exception.
```

However, this is not the problem you are having. The code you have written should work, but you never update the finished variable inside the loop which is why it is never finished. This solution using `break` is better than throwing a new exception inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When acquiring numeric values from user input it's always a good idea to defend against garbage data. This variation on the code in question includes a simple function that can be used for this purpose:

```
from random import randint

def getvalue(prompt, _type=int):
    while True:
        try:
            return _type(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

while True:
    lo = getvalue('Enter low number: ')
    hi = getvalue('Enter high number: ')
    if lo < hi:
        break
    print('Please enter a valid lo/hi range')

number = randint(lo, hi)

while (response := input('Enter guess or "done" to end: ')) != 'done':
    try:
        if (guess := int(response)) == number:
            print('Same - well guessed')
            break
        print('Too low' if guess < number else 'Too high')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: There is an invalid syntax on the while (response := input('Enter guess or "done" to end: ')) != 'done':

Comment: @Proxie You are probably using an out-of-date version of Python. You will need 3.8+. The current version is 3.10.7